# Change font of text in TableView after initialize

Tags: java, fonts, javafx, tableview

I would like to change the font of the text in my `TableView`, but when I try it like this, it is not applying the font, because it can not find any nodes:

```
tableView.lookupAll(".table-row-cell").forEach(cell -> {
    applyFont(cell, MainFont.LIGHT, FontStyle.SUBHEAD);
});
```

where `applyFont()` is a custom function. I thought it had something to do with the `TableView` not being initialized, so I tried to wrap it in a `Platform.runLater()`, but this is also not working.

However, the only thing that is working is placing this code in a listener (selection, hover, etc..):

```
tableView.hoverProperty().addListener(change -> {

    tableView.lookupAll(".table-row-cell").forEach(cell -> {
        applyFont(cell, MainFont.LIGHT, FontStyle.SUBHEAD);
    });

});
```

When I now hover the `TableView` the font changes. But I do not get why it is not working with `Platform.runLater()`.

This code is located in the superclass of each screen in my application, and is run after the subscreen has been build, but has not been shown.

What am I missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Note: I can not use a CSS solution in my case.

Comment: Why can you not use CSS? This is the recommended and supported approach for functionality like this. If you really want to do it with a `lookup` (which is still using CSS, really), then you have to make sure CSS has been applied to the table view and all its cells when you perform the lookup. It's not really possible to tell why your code doesn't work without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but most likely you are either trying to do the lookup before the cells are created, or before CSS has been applied to the table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @James_D, but can you tell me when the CSS is applied? And when are the cells created?

Comment: There's no real guarantee when they will happen; this is an implementation detail. Logically, though, they must both occur by the end of the first rendering pulse. You can *try* invoking `layout` to force the cell creation, and `applyCSS()` to apply the CSS. Can't you use a `rowFactory` and set the style on the row? Why don't you just use CSS? Again, it's really impossible to help without an MCVE.

Comment: I can not use a CSS file, because I let the user choose fonts and colors. While I do not know how to create a .css file at runtime, I chose to `setStyle()`. This is working for a lot of cases, such as background colors, however the only thing not working is ".table-row-cell". And I just wonder why the listener is working, and the `Platform.runLater()` is not...

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to say, unless you actually create an MCVE. Of course, `Platform.runLater(...)` makes no guarantee as to when it actually runs, so I don't see how you would use it to ensure CSS has been applied, etc.

Comment: @James_D He's ignoring the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) hint. So it seems to be vain.

Comment: Why should I create one when you already have? You have the code in the button action, where I just leave it in the `start method` (which is in my case the initialize method). And due to the complexity of my application it is pretty hard to come up with a MCVE, so you could also give me some time @NwDx, before bashing in third person

Comment: My MCVE was a hint to you how to make one. And if you read the MCVE Help you should be able to shrink your "complex" application to the two facts of where you want to set the font/color. In your question you never mentioned about a second stage or in which method you try to call your code. You should please first create a MCVE and then ask your question. Otherwise you create a riddle about what really happens.

Comment: @bashoogzaad Where do we already have a MCVE?

Comment: Okay I understand, I now fixed it by setting the style of entire `TableView` and overwritten the parts I wanted another font, such as the `Graphic` and `Placeholder`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, NwDx and James_D

Comment: Your welcome and no harm meant! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find CSS lookups inherently unstable, and my advice is to avoid them whenever possible. They will not find any nodes unless CSS has been applied, which typically happens on the first frame render pulse. In addition, for this use case you need to make sure the table rows and cells have been created. Merely wrapping a lookup in a `Platform.runLater(...)` of course makes no guarantees as to whether these conditions are fulfilled. Additionally, they are not typesafe and rely on string binding, so there are many things that can fail that are not checked by the compiler.

For your use case here, it's enough just to set the style of the table rows. You can do this directly with a `rowFactory`. To be able to update styles at a later time, just create a `StringProperty` to hold the style, and then bind the `styleProperty` of the `TableRow`s to this:

```
StringProperty style = new SimpleStringProperty();

// ...

table.setRowFatory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyDataType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.styleProperty().bind(style);
    return row ;
});
```

Now simply calling `style.set(...)` with a valid CSS style will update the style of the rows (and all the cells the rows contain). This completely avoids the need for a lookup.

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConfigurableFontTable extends Application {

    private StringProperty fontFamily = new SimpleStringProperty(Font.getDefault().getFamily());
    private ObjectProperty<FontWeight> fontWeight = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(FontWeight.NORMAL);
    private BooleanProperty italic = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private IntegerProperty fontSize = new SimpleIntegerProperty((int)Font.getDefault().getSize());

    private ObjectProperty<Color> fontFill = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.BLACK);

    private StringProperty style = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        style.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> String.format(
                "-fx-font-family: %s;\n"
                + "-fx-font-weight: %d;\n"
                + "-fx-font-style: %s;\n"
                + "-fx-font-size: %d;\n"
                + "-fx-text-background-color: rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f);\n",
                fontFamily.get(),
                fontWeight.get().getWeight(),
                italic.get()?"italic":"normal",
                fontSize.get(),
                (int)(255 * fontFill.get().getRed()),
                (int)(255 * fontFill.get().getGreen()),
                (int)(255 * fontFill.get().getBlue()),
                fontFill.get().getOpacity()
            ),
            fontFamily,
            fontWeight,
            italic,
            fontSize,
            fontFill
        ));

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.styleProperty().bind(style);
            return row ;
        });

        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        Button changeStyleButton = new Button("Change style...");
        changeStyleButton.setOnAction(e -> showChangeStyleDialog(primaryStage));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, changeStyleButton, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(changeStyleButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(changeStyleButton, new Insets(10));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showChangeStyleDialog(Stage owner) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();

        root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        ComboBox<String> fontFamilyChoice = new ComboBox<>();
        fontFamilyChoice.getItems().addAll(Font.getFamilies());
        fontFamilyChoice.setValue(fontFamily.get());

        ComboBox<FontWeight> fontWeightChoice = new ComboBox<>();
        fontWeightChoice.getItems().addAll(FontWeight.values());
        fontWeightChoice.setValue(fontWeight.get());

        CheckBox italicCheckBox = new CheckBox("Italic");
        italicCheckBox.setSelected(italic.get());

        ComboBox<Integer> fontSizeChoice = new ComboBox<>();
        fontSizeChoice.getItems().addAll(4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20, 24, 32, 40, 48);
        fontSizeChoice.setValue(fontSize.get());

        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
        colorPicker.setValue(fontFill.get());

        root.addRow(0,  new Label("Font:"), fontFamilyChoice);
        root.addRow(1, new Label("Weight:"), fontWeightChoice);
        root.addRow(2, new Label("Size:"), fontSizeChoice);
        root.add(italicCheckBox, 1, 3);
        root.addRow(4, new Label("Text Color:"), colorPicker);

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            fontFamily.set(fontFamilyChoice.getValue());
            fontWeight.set(fontWeightChoice.getValue());
            fontSize.set(fontSizeChoice.getValue());
            italic.set(italicCheckBox.isSelected());
            fontFill.set(colorPicker.getValue());
            stage.hide();
        });

        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, okButton, cancelButton);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.add(buttons, 0, 5, 2, 1);

        stage.initOwner(owner);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"firstName");
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "email");

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
            this.email.set(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! It is pretty neat to do this with a RowFactory. Also, it seems I need to use bindings more often..

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

You want to set the font style of your TableView. You want to set the style of the font for rows/cells.

#### Solution

You be able to use the method `setStyle()` of class TableView. With the [JavaFX CSS Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) you can see which settings are possible. So this is CSS but without an extra CSS File, so you are able to do it in any way.

#### Change Font Style for the cells of the TableView

A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will look like this:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableFontStyle extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ObservableList<Person> persons
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Sir", "Tobey"),
                    new Person("Admiral", "von Schneider"),
                    new Person("Mr.", "Pommeroy"),
                    new Person("Mr.", "Winterbottom"));

    TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>(persons);

    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

    tableView.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(0);

    Button btn = new Button("Change Font Style");
    btn.setOnAction((e) -> {
      Set<Node> cells = tableView.lookupAll(".table-cell");
      cells.forEach((c) -> {
        c.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:lighter;-fx-font-style:italic;");
      });
    });

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(tableView, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Font Table");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName
            = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");

    public void setFirstName(String value) {
      firstNameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
      return firstName;
    }

    private final StringProperty lastName
            = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");

    ;

    public void setLastName(String value) {
      lastNameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
      return lastNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
      return lastName;
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.firstName.set(firstName);
      this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }
  }
}
```

The working Application will look like this:

[image: App]

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I forgot to mention I only want the style applied on the rows, so thats why I need to lookUp

Comment: That's more complicated without css. Why you cannot use css? Or css file?

Comment: I can use CSS, but not a CSS file. This is because I let the user choose colors and fonts in the application. So I build the CSS on the fly

Comment: I've updated my answer to your needs. This should fit your thing, if a user clicks the button (chooses a color) the table will be updated.

Comment: Sorry, but I let the user change the font and colors in some settings screen, and these options are saved in the Preferences. It is all about when to apply the code. I understand it works on button click, but that is basically the same as in a listener. So the real question is: when to lookUp?

Comment: Setting a color or font is always an Action, so where is the problem? You can even work with properties file to store the selected values from the user to a file. Why you want it async?

Comment: The color and font setting is in another screen, so I want to right font to be shown when the page this is about is initialized.

Comment: Hm, well I think this is not a css issue, this is more a handling issue. If you want that something is available at initialization phase, it should already be there, otherwise you are only able to change it afterwards. And afterwards means you have an Action to do this change.